# 7 Segment Rfid Counter

Tags: c, pic

I have rfid circuits. Im trying to add a counter with a 7 seven segment.
My seven segment giving random numbers like this.[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tRxO.png)
I think these numbers are opposite of my numbers. How can i solve this problem?

```
 #include <16F887.h>    
    #fuses XT,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOBROWNOUT,NOLVP,NOPUT,NOWRT,NODEBUG,NOCPD
    #use delay(clock=4m,oscillator) 
    #define Dig1 PIN_D0
    #define Dig2 PIN_D1
    #define rfid PIN_D2
    #define reset PIN_A1
    #use fast_io(b)
    #use fast_io(d)
    char birler = 0, onlar = 0, sayi = 0;
       void main() 
    {
       int digit[10]={0b0111111,0b0000110,0b1011011,0b1001111,0b1101101,0b1111101,0b0000111,0b1111111,0b1101111};

       set_tris_b(0x00);
       output_b(1);
       set_tris_d(0b11111100);
       output_d(0b11111100);
       output_b(0b11111100);

       while(1)
         {
         output_b(digit[onlar]);
         output_d(0b11111101);
         delay_ms(5);
         output_b(digit[birler]);
         output_d(0b11111110);
         delay_ms(5);

         if(input(rfid) == 0)
         {
            sayi++;
            birler = sayi%10;
            onlar = sayi/10;
            while(input(rfid) == 0)
            {
              output_b(digit[onlar]);
              output_d(0b11111101);
              delay_ms(5);
              output_b(digit[birler]);
              output_d(0b11111110);
              delay_ms(5);

             }
          } 
          }
       }
```

Comment: I hope you are learning that not having a dedicated function that handles _only_ the display is hampering your ability to debug a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should consider isolating the display from your main loop, and eliminating the inline delays in your code.  Pros are increased readability, easier maintenance, and eliminating delays for doing the actual work.

While preparing this response, I found out that your segments table is missing entries.  Entry for '4' is missing.

The code below is far from complete.  There is a digit missing in the LED segments table, you're using a switch that needs debouncing and it lacks a clock for non-blocking timers.

I've copy/pasted much of your app, and added comments...

```
#include <16F887.h>    
#fuses XT,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOBROWNOUT,NOLVP,NOPUT,NOWRT,NODEBUG,NOCPD
#use delay(clock=4m,oscillator) 
#define Dig1 PIN_D0
#define Dig2 PIN_D1
#define rfid PIN_D2
#define reset PIN_A1
#use fast_io(b)
#use fast_io(d)

// never define const arrays on the stack.
static const int digit[10]= { 0b0111111, 0b0000110, 0b1011011, 0b1001111, /* missing '4' */ 0,
                              0b1101101, 0b1111101, 0b0000111, 0b1111111, 0b1101111 };

void display(unsigned char value)
{
    static char tens = 0;
    char dig = (tens) ? (value / 10) : (value % 10);
    dig = digit[dig];
    output_high((tens} ? Dig2 : Dig1);
    output_b(dig);                     // <-- clobbers the high bit of B
    output_low((tens} ? Dig1 : Dig2);  // preventing other uses for it.
    tens = !tens;
}

void main() 
{
   char sayi = 0;

   output_b(1);
   output_d(0b11111100);
   output_b(0b11111100);  // why set PORTB to 1 earlier?  is that a bug?

   set_tris_b(0x00);      // always init tristate AFTER setting output 
   set_tris_d(0b11111100);

   while(1)
   {
     display(sayi);

     if(input(rfid) == 0) // debouncing needed. 30ms is a good delay for debouncing
     {
        sayi++;           // what happens when we reach 100 ???
     }
     delay_ms(30);        // in real-life, this should not be there.
                          // there are better ways to throttle a program, 
                          // including going to sleep/idle.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think these numbers are opposite of my numbers.

Check if your seven segment is [common cathode](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/7-segment-display-tutorial.html) or not, as it seems that the code is built for common cathode seven segment

And if it is common anode and it is your only choice, you can simply change the code to fit it by toggling all the bits in  `digit` array, for ex zero will be `0b10000000`

Comment: It is common cathode and when code send 11,22,33,44,55.. numbers code works normal.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are not appearing correctly, consider changing the digit array to

```
digit[] = {0b1, 0b10, 0b100, 0b1000, 0b10000, 0b100000, 0b1000000};
```

and run each pattern for 5 seconds.  That will tell you which bit is controlling which segment.  What I've noticed about 7-segment displays from different manufacturers is that they don't always number the segments in the same way so 0b111111 may appear as 6 or 9: not necessarily 0.